# Draw pie chart from DataGridView with column name as series

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts, legend, pie-chart

I have a datagridview "regionVolumeTable" and a chart object "pieChart" in C# code with one row of data in the datagridview object and the layout like this

```
DATE   |  NY   |   MA  | CA   | FL  
3/1/13 |  100  |  120  | 150  | 200
```

I am struggling to use the row[0], column[1], [2], [3], [4] which are ("NY", "MA", "CA", "FL") as the legend in the pie chart
and row[1], column[1], [2], [3], [4] which are (100, 120, 150, 200) as the value to draw a pie-chart.

I know I need to sum up column[1...4] from row[1] to get the sum, and then divide each of the sector to get the degree to draw.

So far, I have:

```
for (int colindex = 1; colindex < 5; colindex++)
{
   pieChart.Series.Add((string)regionVolumeTable.Columns[colindex].Name);

}
```

And I don't know how to proceed to finish up to get the values assign to plot the pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

For a `Pie` chart you can only have one `Series`. Add one `DataPoints` for each of your data values:

```
Series s = pieChart.Series.Add("pie");
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
s.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
for (int colindex = 1; colindex < regionVolumeTable.Columns.Count; colindex++)
{
    s.Points.AddXY(regionVolumeTable.Columns[colindex].HeaderText,
                   regionVolumeTable[colindex, 0].Value);
}
```

[image]

Note that is **looks** as if the charts contains several `Series`; but in a `Pie` chart each **`DataPoint`** is shown in the `Legend`!